# Scanner считывание полей

Tags: java

Когда пользователь заполнит все данные, необходимые для создания объектов, будет выполнена проверка всех полей на корректность.

Если пользователь введет неверные данные, хотя бы по одному из полей, то ему будет выдано сообщение об ошибке и дана возможность подкорректировать ввод.

Я не знаю как выполнить это! Я новичок и я не знаю как из других классов вызвать эти переменные поля. Заранее спасибо!

Главный класс:

```
package jara_quest;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Jara_quest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Helicopter h1 = new Helicopter(12,25,3,4,5,6,50);    

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    }

}
```

Класс 1:

```
package jara_quest;

public class Fly{

protected int speed= 400;
protected int height= 25;
protected int distance= 5000;
protected int numOfPass= 20;

public void setSpeed(int speed){this.speed=speed;}
public void setHeight(int height){this.height=height;}
public void setDistance(int distance){this.distance=distance;}
public void setNumOfPass(int numOfPass){this.numOfPass=numOfPass;}

public int getSpeed(){return speed;}
public int getHeight(){return height;}
public int getDistance(){return distance;}
public int getNumOfPass(){return numOfPass;}

     public boolean isFlyng(int height){
    if(this.height<height)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }    

    Fly(int speed,int height,int distance,int numOfPass){
    this.speed=speed;
    this.height=height;
    this.distance=distance;
    this.numOfPass=numOfPass;
    }

}
```

Класс 2:

```
package jara_quest;

public class Helicopter extends Fly {

    int numOfScrew = 8;
    int capacity = 1000;
    int gasFuel = 50;

    public void gasFuel(int gasFuel) {
        this.gasFuel = gasFuel;
    }

    public boolean addFuel(int gasFuel) {
        if(this.gasFuel < gasFuel)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public Helicopter(int speed, int height, int distance, int numOfPass, int numOfScrew, int capacity,int gasFuel) {
        super(speed, height, distance, numOfPass);
    }

}
```

Comment: Вроде у вас там есть методы сеттеры и геттеры. set-методы используются для установки значения поля, get для его получения.

Comment: поля у класса это что? максимальные значения?